# How to show only once time page Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I Want it That One page is only shown once the application starts and the next time go to the Home screen.I'm trying to look into NavigationHelper but doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your App.xaml.cs file, you should have something looking like this code in the `OnLaunched` method:

```
if (rootFrame.Content == null)
{
    // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
    // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
    // parameter
    if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), args.Arguments))
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
    }
}
```

Here, you can check whether the app is launched for the first time (for instance, by storing a value on the phone), and replace the call to `rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), args.Arguments))` by the page you want to navigate to.

Comment: Well, i'm kinda lost here, ok i will store the name of page, but i want after that go to other page, and that previous page not anymore.